# URL Regular Expression in Racket

Tags: regex, url, racket

I'm trying to use the URL regular expression to match URLs in [Racket](http://racket-lang.org/) like this:

```
(regexp-match #rx"((mailto\:|(news|(ht|f)tp(s?))\:\/\/){1}\S+)" "www.test.com/")
```

The problem is that I'm getting this error: `read: unknown escape sequence \: in string`. What should I do to correct this?

---

Now I'm trying this:

```
(regexp-match #px"((mailto:|(news|(ht|f)tp(s?))://){1}\S+)" "www.youtube.com/watch?v=I0r4Wo2Q3l4")
```

And now I'm getting this error: `read: unknown escape sequence \S in string`

Comment: `:` isn't usually a special character in regexes. Why should it be escaped here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a number of issues with your code.  First, as others have pointed out, you don't need to escape the colon character.

Second, you need to use `#px` to start a regular expression that uses perl-regexp extensions, as you've done.

Finally, you've left out the "http://" in the input that makes it match the pattern.

Here's an example that works:

```
#lang racket

(regexp-match #px"((mailto:|(news|(ht|f)tp(s?))://){1}\\S+)"
              "http://www.test.com/")
```

running this code produces:

```
'("http://www.test.com/" "http://www.test.com/" "http://" "http" "ht" "")
```

Answer (score 2):

\:  is an incorrect scape sequence because : isn't a special character did you wanted to write .?

Comment: (regexp-match #px"((mailto:|(news|(ht|f)tp(s?))://){1}\\S+)" "www.youtube.com/watch?v=I0r4Wo2Q3l4")

Comment: I think you need the double \: \\S

Comment: that's because \S is to scape from string, to make a regexp what you need to scape is the \ to then, at the regexp scape read it as \S